# Worklight 6 - Default startup View

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, dojo

Currently I'm using Worklight v6 for developing a hybrid app. We are using Dojo mobile as framework. I want to change the default startup View. First it had to be developed as an app without a login, but after a few decent conversations with the client we found out that a login is required. The problem is that I don't know how to change the default view. Does somebody knows how to change this?

e.g. default view is 'Home.html' at the moment and I want to change it to 'Login.html' ?

Thanks in advance,

Guy

Comment: This is not really a WL or Dojo question... it is a purely applicative logic. Find a place in your code responsible for showing/hiding/changing screens and load login.html instead of home.html

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but if it was that easy I would already found it by myself..I already did a search on 'Home.html' but I can't figure out where it's called as startup screen. I think it will be an easy config setting, but I don't know wich one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application-descriptor.xml file includes the main page that loads.